# How the ReactJS can manage the browser's RAM/CPU resources?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, single-page-application, virtual-dom

Today I have a job interview and they asked me a different question. He said in the Single Page Application (SPA) structure the front-end developers should manage the client resources and cleaning up the other process usages (RAM, CPU).

He said when the clients open more pages or send more requests, the client RAM and CPU will use more and in the future theirs browser will crash or this browser will be slowly because the resource usage is more and more and the components will open on each other.

He said there are many methods to handle this problem, and every body have a different solution for solving this problem. I told him I think the Virtual DOM can solve this problem and by default the ReactJS can support this problem.

He approved but I have doubts who my answer was correct. So, is a right method or solution to manage the SPA clients computer resource's (RAM, CPU)?

Comment: You cant really "manage" it. Thats the browsers job. You just use the ressources and try to be as memory/performance wise as possible. Using React is probably performance wise (to a certain extent) and uses a bit more memory

Comment: @JonasW. Thank you, So there is no a fixed way or certain method to manage this issue ?! I think we can handle the latest components loaded memory usage and cleaning up the background memory for a fresh and clean resource for optimization the app ...

Comment: There is no way to directly do the garabage collection or access the memory directly from javascript, so no, you cant.

Comment: @JonasW. Thank's , And we can not kill the previous process to manage this problem ? because apparently the latest components has loaded and those are just hidden ...

Comment: Which process are you talking about?!?

Comment: @JonasW. The components, For example the client is in projects list page and he change page to services list or edit profile. all of this actions need memory usage to cache or load the api responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser (client) does not give you the ability to directly access system resources like RAM or CPU hence you can't really control these resources. But traversing the DOM too much and making too many frequent API calls can lead to a less performant web app. React does improve rendering through its virtual dom feature which means the DOM only gets updated when it absolutely needs to. Also caching less changing datasets can reduce the number of API calls you web app has to make. In general try not to render huge data in a single page for data-heavy web apps, always use pagination. also, try not to fetch large data in one API call too.

Comment: Thank you, But with manage the loaded components we can not manage the resources usage ? for example delete the old states or manage loaded components ?!

Comment: Unless you're using a state management library like redux, if you navigate away from a specific page to another page in an SPA the state of the previous page would be lost